# ios, how to create #define for URL that will have dynamic variable in it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a global variable which is part of a URL, which will be created on run time using a string from the user.

For example:

```
#define base_URL @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=%@&unit=metrics"
```

also please suggest how should I use it, for example:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", base_URL, string.text];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do the following having `NSString *input`:

`NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:base_URL, input];`

This will replace %@ with the string from `input`

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you've got 2 options

1. Store the variable on a Plist and read it every time you need it
2. Create a singleton which contains the variable

I'd go with 1, but that's a personal choice

Comment: Since both options seem absolutely bizarre to me, could you explain?

Comment: Neither of these are dynamic at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this one?

```
#define BASE_URL(__ARGS__)     [NSString stringWithFormat: @"YOUR_URL%@", __ARGS__]
```

You can use it as:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString: BASE_URL(string.text)];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Example

```
#define URL @"This is %@ Url"
NSString *newStr = [URL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:@"Hello"];
```

Comment: what if the url has two or more %@(user variable)?

Comment: The string is a format string. Why would you use anything other than stringWithFormat? BTW. stringWithFormat works just fine if the replacement is an NSNumber*, while your code will crash.